# ASP.NET entity relationship

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

If I have Visual Studio ASP.NET project. In my project I have a database with 2 tables, parent table with an ID as a primary key and child table with an ID as a foreign key referencing to parent table's primary key. In my child table I keep the records, but I also want to be able to display those records belonging to the right ID so I don't fill my child table with wrong data. What would be the way to do that? Can it be done via some sql statements or only stored procedure?

Comment: If you have a foreign key constraint on the ID column in child table, it will not allow you to add any records in the child table which doesnt have a parent record in parent table.

Comment: I know that, but the thing is that i have it in the parent table.

Comment: Pardon , you have what in the parent table ?

Comment: Same record that I intend to enter in child table.